# What's the meaning to test 'ActionMailer::Base.deliveries.size'?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec

To test rails action mailer code with rspec, it's common to check ActionMailer::Base.deliveries.size like this:

```
it "sends an email successfully" do
  expect { mail.deliver_now }.to change { ActionMailer::Base.deliveries.size }.by(1)
end
```

What's the meaning of this test? What type of bug we can find by this test?

IMO, once I call the deliver method, the mail will sent automatically, that's the ActionMailer responsibility isn't that? Why we need to test ActionMailer functionality in our test code?

Comment: Try to make a typo in your mailer class and you will see why we do test this. It is more like an integration test. We are testing here if our code sends an email.

Comment: I don't think this is a good test. It looks like it belongs to the ActionMailer proyect and not yours. @P.Boro if you want to prevent typos, you could have better and more clear specs (mailer spec for the mailer method, view tests for the template).